# Julian and Gregorian dates from Wikidata

Tags: wikidata, sparql, calendar

How can I get the Julian birth or death date for someone who was born or died under the Julian Calendar (Isaac Newton, for example) on Wikidata using a SPARQL query?

This simple query returns "4 January 1643," which is Newton's Gregorian birth date:

[SELECT ?birthdate
WHERE {
wd:Q935 wdt:P569 ?birthdate .
}](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fbirthdate%0AWHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20wd%3AQ935%20wdt%3AP569%20%3Fbirthdate%20.%0A%7D)

I've Googled (and DDGed) this up and have not come up with an answer.  Any help you could offer would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of April 2018, there is no way (in SPARQL).

The [RDF Dump format](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikibase/Indexing/RDF_Dump_Format#Time) says:

> Note that the calendar model is the original values calendar model even if `wikibase:timeValue` was converted to Gregorian.

[Try](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%2a%20%7B%0A%20%20wd%3AQ935%20p%3AP569%20%5B%20wikibase%3Arank%20%3Frank%20%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20ps%3AP569%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fsimplevalue%20%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20psv%3AP569%20%20%20%20%20%20%5B%20wikibase%3AtimeCalendarModel%20%3Fcalendar%20%3B%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20wikibase%3AtimeValue%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fvalue%20%20%20%20%20%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D%0A%7D) this query:

```
SELECT * {
  wd:Q935 p:P569 [ wikibase:rank ?rank ;
                   ps:P569       ?simplevalue ;
                   psv:P569      [ wikibase:timeCalendarModel ?calendar ; 
                                   wikibase:timeValue         ?value     ]
                 ]
}
```

As you can see, there are two statements (one of them is not [truthy](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikibase/Indexing/RDF_Dump_Format#Truthy_statements)), but the value is *4 January 1643* independently of the calendar model.

```
           rank             simplevalue      calendar          value      
 ------------------------ ---------------- ------------- ---------------- 
  wikibase:NormalRank      4 January 1643   wd:Q1985727   4 January 1643  
  wikibase:PreferredRank   4 January 1643   wd:Q1985786   4 January 1643
```

---

By the way, Wikidata API [returns](https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbgetclaims&entity=Q935&property=P569&props=&format=json) two different dates:

1. ```
   "value": {
             "time": "+1643-01-04T00:00:00Z",
             "timezone": 0,
             "before": 0,
             "after": 0,
             "precision": 11,
             "calendarmodel": "http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q1985727"
            }
   ```
2. ```
   "value": {
             "time": "+1642-12-25T00:00:00Z",
             "timezone": 0,
             "before": 0,
             "after": 0,
             "precision": 11,
             "calendarmodel": "http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q1985786"
           }
   ```